# plotagem de plineplot com seaborn excluindo certos elementos

Tags: python, data, data.frame, gráfico, seaborn

Gostaria de plotar um lineplot com o sns , mas não queria que ele plotasse uma linha em específico

```
sns.set_palette('Accent')
sns.set_style('darkgrid')

ax = sns.lineplot(x=dados['date'],y=dados['cases'],err_style= None,hue=dados['state'])
ax.figure.set_size_inches(15,6)


ax.set_title("Casos de corona vírus no Brasil" , fontsize=18)
ax.set_xlabel("Tempo" , fontsize=14)
ax.set_ylabel("Casos" , fontsize=14)
ax=ax
```

neste caso em específico, gostaria que o sns plotasse dividindo por estado , mas queria excluir o estado de São Paulo do gráfico

url do data set:https://www.kaggle.com/unanimad/corona-virus-brazil

Answer (score 0):

Simplesmente retire as linhas do estado de São Paulo antes de plotar:

```
dados_sem_sp = dados.loc[dados['state'] != 'São Paulo']
ax = sns.lineplot(x=dados_sem_sp['date'], y=dados_sem_sp['cases'], err_style= None, hue=dados_sem_sp['state'])
```